# Использование нескольких ячеек в TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

Как сделать чтобы на экране создавалась нужная(настроенная через код) ячейка исходя от номера строки? Пишет ошибку т.к. cell в конструкции if не имеет таких лейблов. Моя попытка:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!

        if indexPath.row %2 == 0 {

      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Сell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
      let fetch = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myEntity

         cell.nameLabel.text = fetch.textOnLabel
         cell.dateLabel.text = String(fetch.shortDate!)

        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myXibViewCell     
        }

        return cell    
    }
```

Comment: у вас cell объявлен как uitableviewcell, а свойства вы используете из mytableviewcell. не за компом сейчас, но предположу, что вам надо объявить cell без указания класса. что то типа var cell: AnyObject. позже точно напишу

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko спасибо))...вы правы по поводу cell. В этом то и проблема, если обьявить переменную cell внутри конструкции if, то это будет другая cell. Возвращать будет нечего.

Comment: так решил мой совет проблему или нет?

Comment: Нет. Также ругается на то что Value of type AnyObject has no member nameLabel и тд.

Comment: попробуйте что то типа `(cell as myTableViewCell).nameLabel.text = fetch.textOnLabel`

Comment: Спасибо))Выручаете как всегда. Работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: AnyObject! //объявить cell без указания типа

    if indexPath.row %2 == 0 {

  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Сell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell
  let fetch = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myEntity

     //делать каст в myTableViewCell
     (cell as myTableViewCell).nameLabel.text = fetch.textOnLabel
     (cell as myTableViewCell).dateLabel.text = String(fetch.shortDate!)

    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myXibViewCell     
    }

    return cell    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

создайте массив где будете хранить например строки с именами var name = String, в методе numberOfRowsInSection верните name.count, и затем в cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)! as UITableViewCell
cell.titleLabel.text = name[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

и таким образом каждая ячейка будет со своим именем, так же если картинку нужно добавить или любой другой обьект, всё таким способом, используйте массивы

Comment: Я сделал все через xib-ячейки.  Исходя от номера строки создается заранее настроенная ячейка.

Comment: способ который я вам предложил будет быстрее работать, желательно всё делать динамически, для повышения качества вашего приложения